# LEFT JOIN product p ON 1

Tags: mysql

can anyone explain this? ( i have clipped the code to show what i am interested in )

```
SELECT * FROM (
          SELECT * FROM company
          LEFT JOIN product p ON 1
)
```

what does the `LEFT JOIN product p ON 1` mean?

first time i encounter this and it does not really make sense to me.
the question might be stupid and i might get some down votes for it, 
but if you don't ask, you never learn.

i apologize ahead if this looks stupid.

Comment: it says give me all records from the child table (product) for each of the company records based on the relationship p to 1 but the query is bad.

Comment: i was thinking its something like that, but the tables have no relationship and no `product_id` on the company table.
its just bizarre.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bad query. Looks like someone meant to do a join and just pooched it and left it in there.

Comment: it's basically the same as `SELECT * FROM company, product`